# Google Identity Toolkit - Login not working

Tags: php, google-identity-toolkit

I've followed the quickstart guide to setup a basic website in PHP to use the Google Identity Toolkit. The widget on the index.php page displays the 'sign-in' button. When pressed I'm taken to the gitkit.php page and prompted to enter my email address. After doing so I'm taken to a Google site to put in my password. After I do so I'm redirected back to my website but the widget still says 'login' and the index.php page does not recognise that I have signed in. No error messages are displayed through the sign-in process. Have spent a fair bit of time trying to diagnose but not getting anywhere. Hoping somebody can point me in the right direction.

I have setup the hosts file on my computer to point briansfakedomainname.com to a webserver accessible on my LAN.

My index.php page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- 1: Load the Google Identity Toolkit helpers -->
<?php
  set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . __DIR__ .'/identity-toolkit-php-master/vendor/google/apiclient/src');
  require_once __DIR__ . '/identity-toolkit-php-master/vendor/autoload.php';

  $gitkitClient = Gitkit_Client::createFromFile(dirname(__FILE__) . '/identity-toolkit-php-master/gitkit-server-config.json');
  $gitkitUser = $gitkitClient->getUserInRequest();
  
?>
<!-- End modification 1 -->
<!-- 1: Configure the sign-in button -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.gstatic.com/authtoolkit/js/gitkit.js"></script>
<link type=text/css rel=stylesheet href="//www.gstatic.com/authtoolkit/css/gitkit.css" />
<script type=text/javascript>
  window.google.identitytoolkit.signInButton(
    '#navbar', // accepts any CSS selector
    {
      widgetUrl: "/gitkit.php",
      signOutUrl: "/index.php",
   cookiePolicy: "single_host_origin",
    }
  );
</script>

<!-- End modification 1 -->

</head>
<body>

<!-- 2: Include the sign in button widget with the matching 'navbar' id -->
<div id="navbar"></div>
<!-- End modification 2 -->

<!-- 2: Print the user information if a signed in user is present -->
<p>
  <?php if ($gitkitUser) { ?>
    Welcome back!<br><br>
    Email: <?= $gitkitUser->getEmail() ?><br>
    Id: <?= $gitkitUser->getUserId() ?><br>
    Name: <?= $gitkitUser->getDisplayName() ?><br>
    Identity provider: <?= $gitkitUser->getProviderId() ?><br>
  <?php } else { ?>
    You are not logged in yet.
  <?php } ?>
</p>
<!-- End modification 2 -->
</body>
</html>
```

My gitkit.php page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <!-- Copy and paste here the "Widget javascript" you downloaded from Developer Console as gitkit-widget.html -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.gstatic.com/authtoolkit/js/gitkit.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//www.gstatic.com/authtoolkit/css/gitkit.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var config = {
  widgetUrl: 'http://briansfakedomainname.com',
  signInSuccessUrl: '/log.php',
  signOutUrl: '/index3.php',
  oobActionUrl: '/email.php',
  apiKey: 'AIzaSyCrPO3VTtkeBg5F3Ssx_IIQuVFgSm1GBHM',
  siteName: 'this site',
  signInOptions: ["password","google"]

      };
      // The HTTP POST body should be escaped by the server to prevent XSS
      window.google.identitytoolkit.start(
          '#gitkitWidgetDiv', // accepts any CSS selector
          config,
          'JAVASCRIPT_ESCAPED_POST_BODY');
    </script>

    <!-- End modification -->

  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Include the sign in page widget with the matching 'gitkitWidgetDiv' id -->
    <div id="gitkitWidgetDiv"></div>
    <!-- End identity toolkit widget -->

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey Brian did you set up your widget url gitkit.php in the developer console? After you sign in via google, you should first be redirected to the widget url which completes the sign in process and then on sucesss redirects to the sign in success url. This happens seamlessly. Also make sure both the widget and sign in success url have the same domain name as you are using single host origin cookie policy.